# Do we want a new custom meta-close reason "Is intended for the main site"?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, close-reasons, meta

One of the most common reasons to close a meta question is that it is just a misplaced post intended for the main site.

Since this is an error mainly committed by new users, I think it could make sense to  have a close reason that is detailed and specific to this situation.

The intent of this post is to see if others would also find this convenient, and if this is the case, to craft the text for the custom reason.

Comment: Sure, why not. We're only using two of the five available slots (assuming meta works like main), I don't see how that could hurt... I wouldn't want a migration path to be opened though, people who ask on meta instead of main typically ask subpar questions, and then we get rejected migrations and undeletable posts...

Comment: Indeed in a draft, I had a remark why migration is often not a good idea along these lines; there used to be a mig-path. But then I realized  that one is gone globally so this is not an option anyway.

Comment: Related to the comment made by @quid about migration paths to main: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19984/do-not-reject-migrations-from-the-meta-site-to-the-main-site

Comment: Well, we wouldn't need to auto-move posts. There's no reason that a question cannot be closed for being meant for the main site when it is appropriate on the main site. And then closed as sub-par on here when it is just sub-par in general. I don't see no reason why we cannot close for more than one reason.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck it is not clear to me what you want to say.

Comment: I said exactly what I said. There shouldn't be a problem with migrating posts as long as me migrate appropriately.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck if you want to say that we should migrate those posts that are good for the main site, and close yet not migrate those that are not good, than this  abstractly makes some sense, would be difficult in practice though. Yet, most of all it is purely hypothetical, since whatever we discuss there is no option to migrate any more, and I highly doubt it will come back.

Comment: Of course. This is a purely hypothetical question about policy. That's what makes it enjoyable and not something stressful. If we were actually deciding a policy, I'd prefer the mods to make that decision, not random community members. :p

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Proposal for the custom reason (comments welcome):

> This question appears to be about mathematics. However, you posted it on the [meta site](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) attached to the site [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com). The meta site is intended for technical support questions and discussions related to the main site. Please post your question on the main site instead: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask. For further information see: [How to ask?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

---

Aggressively cut version to make the 400 character limit (it's 398). The items in `[]` link to the same pages as above.

> You posted this mathematics question on the meta site attached to the site [main]. The meta site is intended for support questions and discussions about the main site (cf. the [meta-help]). Please post your question on the main site instead: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask. For further information see: [ask] and [How to ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959)

Comment: There should probably be a mention of [How to ask a good question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959). I suspect people posting on the wrong site could more often than not profit from some of the advice.

Comment: Is this ever going to be implemented? (Pinging @Daniel)

Comment: @Asaf 6-8 weeks probably. I'll ask what the others think.

Comment: Aaarghhh. 202 characters too long. It would fit if we drop the last sentence, but I'd prefer to keep that. Any good ideas how to cut it down to 400 characters? @Lord_Farin?

Comment: @DanielFischer Clocking in at 398: You posted this mathematics question on the meta site attached to the site [main]. The meta site is intended for support questions and discussions about the main site (cf. the [meta-help]). Please post your question on the main site instead: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask. For further information see: [ask] and [How to ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959)

Comment: @Lord_Farin If the close reason banner supports the short-cuts `[main]` etc., that's great. I'll ask around whether somebody knows if that's the case.

Comment: @Lord_Farin It seems the magic links work, yay!

Comment: @DanielFischer Great news :D.

Comment: @Daniel: I was promised 6-8 weeks, which is 42-56 days. I demand a refund. The implementation took only three days, four if you want to be generous. >:(