# Text in “Closed“ box goes beyond right boundary (on mobile devices)

Tags: bug, status-review, closed-questions, design

On mobile devices, the text in a “Closed” box may extend beyond the right boundary of the box.

Up to now, I observed this only on the Mathematics Meta site, and only for questions which are closed because they should be on the main site.

As an example, here is a screenshot from [Standard deviation in function of population size](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35584/standard-deviation-in-function-of-population-size), taken on an iPhone SE 2020:

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing that the cause of this issue was the full URL (which is a long uninterrupted string of text) in the guidance shown in the post notice for this custom close reason. It's easy enough for the CMs (us) to fix the problem in this particular case by removing/formatting the link (since only staff can edit active close reasons; without staff intervention, mods can only add new ones or deactivate existing ones)... But before I do that, I'll wait to see if the devs can fix the underlying issue that causes the text to extend outside the post notice's borders.

Comment: That said, is there a reason for this to be a custom close reason in the first place, rather than simply having a mod migrate them? (...It looks like [the discussion that led to this custom close reason being created](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22882/414985) suggests that it's because "people who ask on meta instead of main typically ask subpar questions", – but the current close reason text already directs them to ask on the main site anyway, and "subpar questions" can still be improved before/after migration.)

Comment: I see it as a "give a man a fish" vs "teach a man to fish" situation.

Comment: @V2Blast In case you will be formatting the bare link in this close reason, there are a couple more improvements that could be made (HTTP to HTTPS, `meta.math` to `math.meta`, etc.) that I noted in some [chat messages](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62874795#62874795).