# The [mobile-web] tag info is outdated

Tags: discussion, design, meta, tag-wikis, mobile-web

The [mobile-web](/questions/tagged/mobile-web) tag info

> For questions about the mobile versions of Stack Exchange sites. You can access the mobile version of a site by clicking the "mobile" link in the page footer.

is outdated because there are no “mobile versions” of the sites anymore, and there is no “mobile” link in the page footer, see [Deprecating our mobile views](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367609/deprecating-our-mobile-views) :

> On March 2, 2022 we removed the Mobile button from the footer. This means the mobile views are removed entirely from Stack Overflow.

The [mobile-web](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/mobile-web/info) tag info on the main meta now states

> DO NOT USE THIS TAG FOR NEW QUESTIONS UNLESS THEY ARE ABOUT CHAT! Use
> in combination with [chat] for posts about the mobile versions of the
> chat sites. The mobile views of the main sites have been removed.
> [...]
> For questions about the site's current design on mobile-sized screens
> and devices, use responsive-design instead.

I suggest that the [mobile-web](/questions/tagged/mobile-web) tag info is updated in a similar spirit, something like

> DO NOT USE THIS TAG FOR NEW QUESTIONS. This used to be for questions
> about the mobile versions of Stack Exchange sites.
>
> For new question about the design of the Mathematics site on mobile-sized screens and
> devices, use [design](/questions/tagged/design) instead.

Of course most question about design or display problems on specific devices would be posted on the main meta, but there [are cases](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35588/42969) where such problems seem to occur on Mathematics only.

Comment: Good call.  I suggest that you make the tag-wiki edits.

Comment: @XanderHenderson: Thanks for the confirmation.  I'll wait a bit if there is any feedback regarding the wording, then I'll edit the tag-wiki.

Comment: But I’m browsing this on my phone…

Comment: @PlaceReporter99: There used to be two versions of each Stack Exchange site: A "desktop” version and a “mobile” version. That is no longer the case. Now there is a single version of each Stack Exchange site, with a so-called “responsive design” which means that it adapts to all kind of devices (iPhones, Tables, Desktop computes, different screen sizes, ...) automatically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have updated the [mobile-web](/questions/tagged/mobile-web) usage guidance and tag wiki. The use of this tag for new questions is now discouraged in favor of [design](/questions/tagged/design).